# Setting caption in the middle of button image/icon using Vaadin

Tags: css, uibutton, vaadin

[image]Through CSS i am able to get the v.nativebutton looking the way i want to, but i can't get the caption to be right in the middle of my icon/image. Attached is the screen shot of what the button looks like when i add text -align: center to my CSS style sheet. Any idea on how i can set the caption of the button to be right in the middle of my icon image? I want to show the 'Students' label inside the circle?

CSS IM USING:

```
.v-nativebutton-center-text .v-nativebutton-caption {
display: block;
white-space: normal;
text-align: center;
}
.v-nativebutton::-moz-focus-inner {
border: none;
padding: 0;
 }
 .v-nativebutton-center-text span {
  font-size: x-small;
  text-shadow: #fafafa 1px 1px 0;
}
.v-nativebutton-center-text img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px;

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have invoked

button.addStyleName("center-text");

on your native button, the following CSS will center the text:

The following CSS will center the caption accross line breaks:

```
.v-nativebutton-center-text .v-nativebutton-caption {
    display: block;
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding that CSS you suggested and it showed the caption towards the right of the image. I added the CSS i am using on that particular button. Doesn't show the caption in the middle of the image

Comment: the problem was the size of my image. I had to match it up. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Warz Why would you accept this as the answer if it doesn't resolve your problem?

Comment: @b1naryatr0phy The reason i accepted this as the answer was due to the css provided. I ended up using both the `text-align` & `white-space` properties along with resizing my image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced with vaadin so I apologize if my advice isn't relevant to vaadin, but I'll go ahead and chime in anyway!

It might be helpful to post the code you have (the css and html of the specified elements) but I think I can help still.

I would suggest setting the positioning of the circle element to relative and the positioning of the caption to absolute and then position the caption in the middle. Here's one solution:

```
#circle {
    position: relative;
}

#caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px; /* Whatever half of the circle is */
    left: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -25px /* Sets margin-left to half of the width of the caption */
}
```

If you set the #circle positioning to relative and the #caption positioning to absolute, it will place the caption in the top right corner of the circle, on top of it. You can then set the "top" property to half of the total height of the circle to place it in the center of the circle on the y-axis. If you set the caption's left property to 50% and then give it a negative left margin equal to half its width, it should center it perfectly. Make sure you set the #circle to relative positioning, or the caption might be positioned absolutely relative to the entire page as opposed to just the circle.

If this doesn't work, let me know because there are some other possible solutions too. One involves using margin: 0 auto for the centering of the caption instead.

I hope this helps!

Comment: i added my CSS. I am trying to implement your approach by messing with the image (circle) and caption position. could you elaborate?